# How can I sync only changed events via ics?

Tags: ios, synchronization, icalendar

I have been trying to set up synchronization of my iPhone to a remote server where i dynamically generate an ics file. I have added it as a subscribed calendar on my iPhone /iPad, however when i try to send only the updated events through my ics file based on the If-Modified-Since header (which i get in the http request), the events which have not changed get wiped out.
What am i missing???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the http header usge for notification is not part of the icalendar / imip / itip RFC.

icalendar requires that updated events keep the same uid but update the `sequence` property. however you will need in your calendar to keep the unchanged events.